# Detrending positive data, avoiding negative data

Tags: time-series, trend

I am constantly dealing with data detrending problems and am well versed on this topic. One issue I have concerns data that is greater than or equal to zero such as daily rainfall data, snow depth data, wind speed data, etc.

When detrending such data one has to be careful that:
- 0 value remain 0
- negative values are not created

For this reason we often detrend using multiplicative detrending as in x% more or less.

This way the 2 above tests are respected. But I am not entirely satisfied with this approach and I wonder if there is a better way I could investigate. Before any mentions, log detrending is ill suited.

Comment: Maybe take 1st differences (i.e. replace $x_t$ by $x_t-x_{t-1}$)? That can create zero or negative values but it's a classical method if you want to go further in analysing your time series data.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I do not think that looking at the timeseries of difference is the right approach. If you think ahead, once you would detrend that series you will need to go back to the series of x(t) and the problem of 0 becoming non zero or negative value would reappear. I would also like to add that the main issue with multiplicative detrending is that it can have a profound impact on the shape of the probability distribution of the data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to re-scale your data on the real domain. If the log transform does not work, then try another transform. Then take differences, say.